# Error de javafx en IntelliJ Idea "java:cannot acces javafx.application.Application"

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

Ayuda, instale openjavafx 11.02 pero al tratar de ejecutar un proyecto en intelliJ me aparece este error:

Error:(3, 26) java: cannot access javafx.application.Application
  bad class file: /home/jsandi321/Descargas/openjfx-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar!/javafx/application/Application.class
    class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Y no logro que funcione, estoy usando jdk 8

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX fue removido del JDK desde la liberación de Java 11 y aunque este era parte del JDK 8 hace algún tiempo esta versión a sido descatalogada y ya no tiene actualizaciones. Por tal motivo a día de hoy el JDK 8, a pesar de ser LTS, no incluye JavaFX.

Lo anterior te obliga a trabajar con JavaFX 11 o superior, la cual solo es compatible con Java 11 o superior (cada versión de JavaFX coincide con la versión mínima del JDK con la que es compatible). Por lo tanto no puedes trabajar con JavaFX 11 sobre el JDK 8, debes usar el JDK 11 o superior.

Hay otras distribuciones del JDK 8 que si incluyen todavía JavaFX (según [esta respuesta en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974003/javafx-comes-with-jdk-8#answer-35998804)) pero yo nunca las he utilizado.

Mi recomendación es que, siempre que sea posible, actualizar al JDK 11.

Sitio oficial de JavaFX - https://openjfx.io/
Sitio oficial para la descarga de JavaFX - [Gluon JavaFX](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)